# Using MVC SiteMapProvider and DynamicNodeProvider in MVC site for CRUD operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to get MvcSiteMapProvider to work with a simple site which performs some CRUD operations. I'm almost accomplished that, but I'm getting strange behaviour in many scenarios.

First, I created the Controller and Views using stardard hierachy:
Controllers 
  --> EquipoController 
Views 
  --> Equipo --> Index / Details / Create / Edit / Delete...

Next, defined my mvc.sitemap

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Inicio" controller="Home">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Equipo" controller="Equipo">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Crear Equipo" action="Create"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Detalle Equipo" action="Details" dynamicNodeProvider="MvcApplication2.TestDynamicNodeProvider, MvcApplication2">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Editar Equipo" action="Edit"></mvcSiteMapNode>
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Eliminar Equipo" action="Delete"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Note that Edit and Delete operations are nested in Details node.

Next, I implemented the TestDynamicNodeProvider class as follows:
    public class TestDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();

```
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        // Build value 
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

        // Create a node for each album 
        foreach (var equipo in db.GEN_EQUIPO)
        {
            DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
            node.Title = equipo.DESCRIPCION;
            node.RouteValues.Add("id", equipo.ID);                
            yield return node;                
        }            
    }
}
```

Supose that I have two items in GEN_EQUIPO (EQUIPO_A and EQUIPO_B). These are the breadcrumbs I get in every view: 
Index: Inicio > Equipo (easy...)
Details view (2nd item): Inicio > Equipo > EQUIPO_B (ok) 
Edit view (2nd item): Inicio > Equipo > **EQUIPO_A** > Editar Equipo (wrong!)
Delete view (2nd item): Inicio > Equipo > **EQUIPO_A** > Eliminar Equipo (wrong!)

I can't figure why in edit and delete view it builds the breadcrumb using always the first item on the list. Also the link is wrong (*Equipo/Details/1* when it should be *Equipo/Details/2*)

I attach a capture for more example.

I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong! Any idea?

[image: Look at direction bar... and then to the link generated. Also, see that TALADRO is not TRONZADORA!]

Comment: One month after and not a single answer. Maybe my question is bad written? Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "preservedRouteParameters" to your details, edit and delete nodes? I would assume you're using a field such as "id" so it would look like:

preservedRouteParameters="id"

Comment: Added `preserveRouteParameters="id"` to details node and now the links are built with correct urls (localhost:62974/Equipo/Details/2), but the text still fails (displaying TALADRO instead of TRONZADORA)